# Can anyone please tell me how can I make 'str' variable print along with space?

Tags: javascript

```js
const rows = 3;

for (let i = rows - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let space = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    space += ' ';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
    let str = '';
    for (let l = 0; l <= k; l++) {
      str += '*';
    }
  }
  console.log(space + str);
}
```

Comment: You must put the `console.log` inside the `k`-loop, or the `str` declaration outside it.

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined within a for loop only exist within the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of that loop, once the loop ends it ceases to exist.

You can access access a parent scoped variable *within* a nested scope as you're doing with `space += ' '`. However, you can't access a variable defined in the nested scope outside of that new, internal scope.

Move your variable into the proper scope and your code will execute correctly.

**Further Reading:**

- [Codecademy: Scope Cheatsheet](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript/modules/learn-javascript-scope/cheatsheet)
- [MDN: Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)
- [Wikipedia: Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

```js
// Scope 1: rows
const rows = 3;

for (let i = rows - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  // Scope 2: rows, space, str, i
  let space = '';
  let str = ''; // Move here, now it works outside of the k-loop.

  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    // Scope 3: rows, space, str, i, j
    space += ' ';
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
    // Scope 4: rows, space, str, i, k
    for (let l = 0; l <= k; l++) {
      // Scope 5: rows, space, str, i, k, l
      str += '*';
    }
  }

  // Still Scope 2: rows, space, str, i
  console.log(space + str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for.
In your case, the log function did not 'see' the `str` variable because it was used outside the third for-loop (`for (let k = 0;...`).

```js
const rows = 3;

for (let i = rows - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let space = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    space += ' ';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
    let str = '';
    for (let l = 0; l <= k; l++) {
      str += '*';
    }
    console.log(space + str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'str' variable isn't defined in the context where your console.log is. Quickest way would be to move 'let str = "" '  up to where you declare 'space'

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `str` inside the second inner `for` loop, so it will only be accessible within that loop. You can define it within the outer loop and then reset it within the inner loop, then your print statement will be able to access it.

```js
const rows = 3;

for (let i = rows - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let space = '';
  let str = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    space += ' ';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
    str = '';
    for (let l = 0; l <= k; l++) {
      str += '*';
    }
  }
  console.log(space + str);
}
```